# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\User::hasAnyRole()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission, laravel-ui

I'm using Laravel-Permissions and wrote in rotes\web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', function () {
        return "Test";
    });
});
```

I added in app\Http\Kernel.php :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
    'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
    'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
];
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: please share your User model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to include the roles trait

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles; //this line

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have got same error Call to undefined method App\\Models\\User::roles(), in laravel nova 4 with spatie/laravel-permission model, this is the correct answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `User` model uses the `Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles` trait.

```
<?php

use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User
{
    use HasRoles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you did not add this :

`use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;`

```
class User
{
    use HasRoles;
}
```